# Understanding git submodule and "freezing" it at a specific commit hash or version

Tags: git, git-submodules

Assuming the following project layout:-

```
mainrepo_git
    |____ .git
    |____ .gitmodules
    |____ proj            <------- directory containing the code files for mainrepo
            |____ 3rdpartysourcecode <-- directory containing upstream open source code
            |      |____ .git
            |      |____ 3rdpartyfiles
            |
            |____ mainrepofilesanddirectories
```

**mainrepo_git** contains source code I am directly responsible for.  I have read/write access and can push and pull directly to a remote git repository which I manage.

Nested inside **mainrepo_git** is a directory which I named **3rdpartysourcecode**.  This **3rdpartysourcecode** directory is in fact another git repo (also commonly referred to as a "git submodule") which is pointing to an open source 3rd party git repository managed by other developers. I only have read access to it. No write access.

Is there any way of 'freezing' a specific commit hash of the git submodule in relation to a commit made in my main repository?

For example, if I am at (or I revert to) commit *a12ucak* in my mainrepo, my git submodule also gets reverted to a specific version which I tie to commit *a12ucak*?  And when I switch to commit *b349jdsak*, my git submodule also gets reverted to a version which I tie to *b349jdsak*?

**So my question is:** there is a way to create a linkage between a specific commit in the main repo with a corresponding commit in the git submodule? In such a way where when I checkout that specific commit in the main git repo, the corresponding commit in the git submodule will also be checkout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Freezing is the whole point of submodules.  You should really read a tutorial on it.  In a nutshell, `git add 3rdpartysourcecode` (important no trailing slash!) followed by a commit locks the currently checked out submodule commit to the supermodule commit.  Then later you use `git submodule update` to check out that revision.

Comment: Correct. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194