# How to store a specific checkout of a submodule in .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

My project has dependencies. The dependencies are added as submodules.

A given submodule released a new major version that breaks my code.

In my personal copy I may `cd into submodule folder` `git checkout specific version` to fix this.

How do I store this specific version in a way that any fresh `git clone; git submodule update --init --recursive` comes with the correct version for the submodule?

- Perhaps in `.gitmodules`?
- "It's currently not possible and you should just add that specific version library code directly into your repository" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding git submodule and "freezing" it at a specific commit hash or version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238426/understanding-git-submodule-and-freezing-it-at-a-specific-commit-hash-or-versi)

Comment: Freezing is the whole point of submodules. But you have to avoid `git submodule add -b`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+specific+commit